# Pandas DataFrame as body of FastAPI's JSONResponse

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, fastapi

I have a Pandas DataFrame with several columns and some data that I need to return in a response body from a FastAPI application. Borrowing the DataFrame example from another similar, but different, question:

```
test_list = [["Joe", 34, "Accounts", 10000], ["Jack", 35, "Chemistry", 20000], ["Jill", 37, "Art", 2000]]
df = pandas.DataFrame(data=test_list, columns=["Name", "Age", "Dept.", "Salary"])
```

Now if I try to use dataframe.to_json as follows, the returned body is a string with every quote character escaped and is not JSON:

```
result = df.to_json(orient="records") #creates a json string
return JSONResponse(content = result)
```

The above returns something like:

```
"[{\"Name:\":\"Joe\", \"Age\":\"34\"},  ...etc"
```

The following works (in that the returned body is valid JSON) but I don't like that the response is returned as plain text instead of JSON. Is there a better, more proper way to do this?

```
result = df.to_json(orient="records") 
return PlainTextResponse(content = result)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `json`, convert it to `dict` which `fastapi` should be able to handle automatically:

```
result = df.to_dict('records')
return JSONResponse(content = result)
```

Comment: Wow, that worked! Thanks. I thought I tried it earlier today and it was throwing some sort of exception, but I must have made some sort of mistake. I will accept this answer as soon as the website allows me

Comment: From the FastAPI docs, 'When you return a Response directly its data is not validated, converted (serialized), nor documented automatically.' Any concern for this, or follow up code edit? As the docs also indicate it can still be done, however. Separately, I believe FastAPI will return as JSON automatically. A return with `df.to_json(orient="records") ` is a double dip, and likely responsible for the added back slashes.